# Generating resources in AAR using gradle as part of the application

Tags: android, gradle, android-glide, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I got library which includes some resource generating. I have the task for doing generating resources:

```
val updateWidgetResourcesProvider = tasks.register<Copy>("updateWidgetResources") {
    from("../../widget/")
    include("*.png")
    into("$sharedResLocation/raw")
    rename { "asset_$it".replace("@", "_").toLowerCase() }
}
android.libraryVariants.all {
    android.sourceSets[this.name].res.srcDirs(sharedResLocation)
    mergeResourcesProvider.configure {
        dependsOn(updateWidgetResourcesProvider)
    }
}
```

When I run `:myLibrary:build` everything works just perfect.

I also have an app, which uses library as dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":myLibrary"))
}
```

Problem starts when I'm building `:app:build`. Task `updateWidgetResourcesProvider` simply not getting executed. How do I make a resource generating task so it both executed when I'm calling `:app:build` and `:myLibrary:build`. Also, why `myLibrary`'s resource merger is not called when it is part of `:app:build` task?

I would appreciate any help, also, if I could read about android gradle task tree, and why it is different when I build AAR by itself or library as part of APK/Bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things, I found a solution.

```
tasks.create<Copy>("updateWidgetResources") {
    val widgetResLocation = "$buildDir/generated/widgetResources"
    from("../../widget/")
    include("*.png")
    into("$widgetResLocation/raw")
    rename { "asset_$it".replace("@", "_").toLowerCase() }
    val task = this
    android.libraryVariants.all {
        registerGeneratedResFolders(files(widgetResLocation) {
            builtBy(task)
        })
    }
}
```